# How to increase the value of a trackbar/Slider in a third party application using sendmessage and c#?

Tags: c#, winapi, slider, sendmessage

HI,
I am looking to increase and decrease the value of a slider/trackbar in a third party application. is it possible to do the same using sendMessage(). I have got the handle of the slider. Could some one  help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First define SendMessage function like this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Then update slider position like this

```
uint TBM_GETPOS = 0x0400;
uint TBM_SETPOS = 0x0405;

IntPtr hWnd = ...
IntPtr pos = SendMessage(hWnd, TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hWnd, TBM_SETPOS, 1, pos.ToInt32() + 1);
```

Get max and min available position using

```
uint TBM_GETRANGEMAX = 0x0402;
uint TBM_GETRANGEMIN = 0x0401;

IntPtr max = SendMessage(hWnd, TBM_GETRANGEMAX, 0, 0);
IntPtr min = SendMessage(hWnd, TBM_GETRANGEMIN, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. let me have a try. But Is there any way to directly pass the handle got from spy++ in the above function?

Comment: I don't have experience with spy++.

Comment: But you can get window handle using hDlg = FindWindow(lpClassName, lpWindowName) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx)
and control handle using GetDlgItem(hDlg, nIDDlgItem) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481(v=vs.85).aspx)
The required information (class name, window name, ID of dlg item) can be probably optained from spy++.

Comment: @sidon you saved my autoit script